# How to make something similar as an if statement in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, conditional-statements

This is my SQLite file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COTXE (                 /*Table to create the cars*/
    matricula   VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   /*CarPlate*/
    marca       INTEGER,                           /*Brand*/
    color       INTEGER                            /*Color*/
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLASA (                 /*Table to crate all the sites of the parking*/
    pos         INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,      /*Number of the parkingsite*/
    superficie  INTEGER,                           /*How many m² it has*/
    ocupada     BOOL                               /*If its empty or not (0 = empty)*/
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS APARCAR (               /*Table to park a car in a site of the parking*/
    pos_plaça   INTEGER,                           /*Number of the parking site*/
    matricula   VARCHAR(7),                        /*Carplate*/
    data_in     DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,         /*Date when it enters the parking*/
    data_out    DEFAULT NULL,                      /*Date when it leaves the parking*/
    PRIMARY KEY (matricula, data_in),              
    FOREIGN KEY (pos_plaça) REFERENCES PLASA(pos),
    FOREIGN KEY (matricula) REFERENCES COTXE(matricula)
);


/*Inserts to add cars and parking sites*/
INSERT INTO COTXE VALUES ('9882JPX', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO COTXE VALUES ('1111DDD', 4, 9);
INSERT INTO COTXE VALUES ('2222SSS', 8, 8);
INSERT INTO COTXE VALUES ('3333FFF', 3, 5);

INSERT INTO PLASA (superficie, ocupada) VALUES (50, 0);
INSERT INTO PLASA (superficie, ocupada) VALUES (34, 0);
INSERT INTO PLASA (superficie, ocupada) VALUES (24, 0);
```

I've got a little problem and its when i try to add, for example the first car two times in the same parking site without leaving in any of those it adds again the same car in the same parking site that should be impossible, i drop here an example:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO APARCAR (pos_plaça, matricula) VALUES (1, '9882JPX');
sqlite> UPDATE PLASA SET ocupada = 1 WHERE pos = 1;
sqlite> INSERT INTO APARCAR (pos_plaça, matricula) VALUES (1, '9882JPX');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM APARCAR;
pos_plaça   matricula   data_in              data_out  
----------  ----------  -------------------  ----------
1           9882JPX     2022-03-17 17:41:24            
1           9882JPX     2022-03-17 17:41:26
```

So i'm asking you guys if any of you know how to condition the INSERT INTO and before adding the car in that parking site, check if its full.

Sorry for my bad english and explanations.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-iif/

Comment: Or maybe this https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/

Comment: According unique index should help - it prevents duplicated value insertion. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3cf11a5577dd0a7e9dfafc431c6ef77a

Comment: You are looking for a [unique constraint](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/unique.php)

Comment: or chapter [3.6. UNIQUE constraints](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) of the fine SQLITE-manual